# Sort excel 2007 pivot table descending by last column with VBA

Tags: excel, sorting, vba, pivot

Thanks guys! I think I may have explained my problem a bit vague. I'm attaching two print screens in order to illustrate my problem.

Print screens: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/illustrasjon.jpg

My pivot table shows stops [minutes] due to specified reasons on a production line. The 'Totalt' column of the week (in which the number of production days vary) is what I wish to focus on in order to allocate improvement efforts to the right place. The sorting will be performed on a daily basis by others than me, and they really should have a button to press rather than sorting via the options bar.

NB! The 'Sum' column is not part of the pivot table. That's just a calculation of the 'Totalt' column to a fixed column in order to make a sector chart of the sorted result, since it's not possible to make a pivot chart from the 'Totalt' column.

The 'Mål per dag' column is just the daily (minutes) goal within which I wish to keep the production stops of a specified reason, so this should be kept out of the 'Totalt' column, but this is less important.

---

I have a pivot table filtered by weeks showing any number of days from one to five. The total column to the right that sums up the values of the days are therefore "moving", and this is why I cannot simply record a macro. I want to create a macro that sort the pivot table descending by the total column.

I do not speak the international language of VBA, but imagine that this is fairly easy for someone who does.

Immensely grateful to anyone willing to write the code for me!

Best regards,
Hans

Comment: Hans, please review my solution. It does not require the user to resort the pivot table, it only requires you to sort it correctly once. That setting is saved, and then every time a value changes, the pivot table will automatically re-sort with my code. Try it and let me know if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hans

To start, you should use the built in sort feature on the pivot table as illustrated in the screenshots below.

[image]

Select the column you wish to sort by:

[image]

This might be a little problematic for you because the pivot table doesn't automatically refresh when your data changes. If you want it to update in real time, then you will want to add the "Worksheet_Change" event handler to the VBA code. To do this, hit Alt+F11 to bring up VBA, and on the worksheet containing your source data enter the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here "PivotTable1" will change to match whatever the name of your pivot table is. This name appears in the Ribbon when you have the pivot table selected.

[image]

Now, as you change your data, the table will automatically re-sort as you go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys! I just updated my post with a bit more detailed desrciption of my problem. Sorry if I overlooked something in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hans, welcome to SO. You did not specify which version of Excel in your tags, but here are some Excel 2007 solutions.

It is possible (and helpful!) to do this without VBA. You may be interested in this [Microsoft solution](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-data-in-a-pivottable-or-a-pivotchart-report-HP010175904.aspx).

I would recommend that you select the range of the pivot table with the totals, exclude the header and the grand total, and then go to the Data tab and choose the Sort Z->A. This will sort the totals in descending order (and of course, change the headers to the left).

You can also record a macro to do this if you would like to perform this sort on a regular basis, but that may be more trouble than it is worth.